# Как ввести Datetime в таблицу с помощью Insert into?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Хочу ввести в базу данных значения с клавиатуры

```
   Flight flight = new Flight();
        SqlCommand addflight = new SqlCommand();
        addflight.Connection =Sqlcon;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival Date");
        flight.Arrival = EnterData();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Departure Date");
        flight.Departure = EnterData();
        Console.Write("Enter Flight number=");
        flight.Flight_Number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter City of arrival=");
        flight.City_of_arrival = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter City of departure=");
        flight.City_of_Departure = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Terminal=");
        flight.Terminal = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Flight status=");
        flight.Flight_Status = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Gate=");
        flight.Gate= Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
       // addflight.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Flights(Arrival,Departure,Flight_Number,City_of_arrival,City_of_departure,Terminal,Flight_Status,Gate,ID) VALUES (2007-05-08 12:35:29.123,2007-05-08 12:35:29.123,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,1)";
       addflight.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Flights(Arrival,Departure,Flight_Number,City_of_arrival,City_of_departure,Terminal,Flight_Status,Gate,ID) VALUES("+
            "20120618 10:34:09 AM" + ","+ "20120618 10:34:09 AM" + ","+flight.Flight_Number+","+flight.City_of_arrival+","+flight.City_of_Departure
            +","+flight.Terminal+","+flight.Flight_Status+","+flight.Gate+","+ID+")";
        ID++;
        try
        {
            addflight.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

При использовании команды INSERT INTO выводиться сообщение о Exception на экран.Incorrect Syntax near 10.Что в строке CommandText не так?
Может есть более правильный способ это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не собирайте CommandText через +, используйте параметры:

```
addflight.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Flights(Arrival,Departure,...,ID) VALUES(@Arrival, @Departure .... )";
addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Arrival", flight.Arrival);
addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departure", flight.Departure);
//....
```

И не будет у вас ошибок с парсингом дат и прочих SQL иньекций.